# Error parsing XML: mismatched tag

Tags: java, android, xml

quisiera preguntar porque en este xml me da error, soy muy novato y quiero agregar unas opciones, pero cuando las agrego ahora me salta este error al recopilar, ya pregunté anteriormente en la web en inglés y me dijeron que es porque no cierro las etiquetas de com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358391/xml13-error-error-parsing-xml-mismatched-tag
"Andy" me dejó el código completo, lo intenté poner pero también me dio error, cerré la última etiqueta porque hay una tercera y también me dio error, usé una web para ver el error pero se logró recopilar y al abrir la opción en la app se me cierra porque se salió todo, quisiera saber como es que tengo que colocar el código, y que si pueden alguien me puede explicar que hice mal. Muchas gracias.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/GB_Mods"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:cmwmobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.whatsapp">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="HPWhatsApp 4.0" android:key="cat_wa">
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_preguntas" android:title="HPWhatsApp WEB" android:key="settings_faq" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/updatess" android:key="updates_key" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="Donar" android:summary="Donar al desarrollador" >
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://paypal.me/Hectorc4rp" />
     </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
    <PreferenceScreen android:icon="@drawable/ic_9" android:title="Contactar al desarrollador" android:summary="Habla con Héctor Paez, creador de HPWhatsApp" >
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/themes">
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_descargar" android:title="@string/download_themes" android:key="download_themes" android:summary="@string/download_themes_summary" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/more_preferences" android:key="themes_key" android:summary="@string/more_preferences_summary" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="Más temas" android:summary="Descarga temas hechos por otras personas" >
         <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="http://www.whatsappthemes.net/search/label/GBWhatsApp%20Themes" />
    </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/appearance">
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_1" android:title="@string/conversation_colors" android:key="chat_colors" android:summary="@string/conversation_colors_summary" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_2" android:title="@string/chats_colors" android:key="chats_colors" android:summary="@string/chats_colors_summary" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_3" android:title="@string/popup_colors" android:key="popup_key" android:summary="@string/popup_colors_summary" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_4" android:title="@string/widgets" android:key="widget_key" android:summary="@string/widgets_summary" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_5" android:title="@string/media_sharing_pref" android:key="media_sharing_key" android:summary="@string/media_sharing_pref_summary" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_6" android:title="@string/others" android:key="others_key" android:summary="@string/others_summary" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_7" android:title="@string/gb_lock" android:key="gb_lock" />
    <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/clean_whatsapp_pref" android:key="clean_whatsapp_screen" />
    <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_8" android:title="@string/read_log_pref" android:key="logs_key" />
    <ListPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_lang" android:entries="@array/language_array" android:title="@string/language_title" android:key="gb_language_key" android:defaultValue="0" android:entryValues="@array/language_values" />
    <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/change_font_pref" android:key="gb_fonts" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/GB_About" android:key="cat_about">
    <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="@string/pref_facebook" android:key="facebook" android:summary="@string/pref_sum_facebook" />
    <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twi" android:title="@string/google_plus" android:key="google_plus" android:summary="@string/google_plus_sum" />
    <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="@string/pref_sum_blogger" android:key="about" android:summary="HPWhatsApp" />
    <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="Página de Facebook" android:summary="Regalanos un me gusta en Facebook" >
          <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://facebook.com/todo.para.android.hp" />
    <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_compartir" android:title="@string/GBShare" android:key="share" android:summary="@string/GBShareSum" />
    <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_reportar" android:title="@string/GB_Report" android:key="report" />
    <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="@string/Thanks" android:key="Thanks" />
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Hector!, tanto para el sitio en español como en inglés es muy importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te 
brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!.

Comment: En general esos errores significan que tienes un tag abierto pero no cerrado (o viceversa)

Comment: viendo la pregunta en ingles, veo que debes cambiar         <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="Donar" android:summary="Donar al desarrollador" >
 por  <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="Donar" android:summary="Donar al desarrollador" />

Edita tu pregunta y adjunta el código

Answer (score 0):

El XML tiene una estructura sencilla pero obligatoria. Básicamente, si abres un elemento `<elemento>` debes también cerrarlo `</elemento>`, a menos que el elemento se cierre al momento de abrirse `<elemento/>`. Si identas correctamente, te puedes dar cuenta fácilmente de los errores. También hay [herramientas que te muestran los errores en XML](https://www.xmlvalidation.com). En tu caso, este sería el XML válido:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/GB_Mods"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:cmwmobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.whatsapp">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="HPWhatsApp 4.0" android:key="cat_wa">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_preguntas" android:title="HPWhatsApp WEB" android:key="settings_faq" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/updatess" android:key="updates_key" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="Donar" android:summary="Donar al desarrollador" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://paypal.me/Hectorc4rp" />
         </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
        <PreferenceScreen android:icon="@drawable/ic_9" android:title="Contactar al desarrollador" android:summary="Habla con Héctor Paez, creador de HPWhatsApp" >
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543814805749" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/themes">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_descargar" android:title="@string/download_themes" android:key="download_themes" android:summary="@string/download_themes_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/more_preferences" android:key="themes_key" android:summary="@string/more_preferences_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="Más temas" android:summary="Descarga temas hechos por otras personas" >
             <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="http://www.whatsappthemes.net/search/label/GBWhatsApp%20Themes" />
        </com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/appearance">
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_1" android:title="@string/conversation_colors" android:key="chat_colors" android:summary="@string/conversation_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_2" android:title="@string/chats_colors" android:key="chats_colors" android:summary="@string/chats_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_3" android:title="@string/popup_colors" android:key="popup_key" android:summary="@string/popup_colors_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_4" android:title="@string/widgets" android:key="widget_key" android:summary="@string/widgets_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_5" android:title="@string/media_sharing_pref" android:key="media_sharing_key" android:summary="@string/media_sharing_pref_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_6" android:title="@string/others" android:key="others_key" android:summary="@string/others_summary" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_7" android:title="@string/gb_lock" android:key="gb_lock" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_actualizaciones" android:title="@string/clean_whatsapp_pref" android:key="clean_whatsapp_screen" />
        <com.whatsapp.preference.WaPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_8" android:title="@string/read_log_pref" android:key="logs_key" />
        <ListPreference android:icon="@drawable/ic_lang" android:entries="@array/language_array" android:title="@string/language_title" android:key="gb_language_key" android:defaultValue="0" android:entryValues="@array/language_values" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_temas" android:title="@string/change_font_pref" android:key="gb_fonts" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/GB_About" android:key="cat_about">
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="@string/pref_facebook" android:key="facebook" android:summary="@string/pref_sum_facebook" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twi" android:title="@string/google_plus" android:key="google_plus" android:summary="@string/google_plus_sum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_web" android:title="@string/pref_sum_blogger" android:key="about" android:summary="HPWhatsApp" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_twitter" android:title="Página de Facebook" android:summary="Regalanos un me gusta en Facebook" >
              <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" android:data="https://facebook.com/todo.para.android.hp" />
        </Preference>
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_compartir" android:title="@string/GBShare" android:key="share" android:summary="@string/GBShareSum" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_reportar" android:title="@string/GB_Report" android:key="report" />
        <Preference android:icon="@drawable/ic_Thanks" android:title="@string/Thanks" android:key="Thanks" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```